# ValueError when user input contains a space

Tags: python, valueerror

The following code gets the user input, then outputs the backward English alphabet version of every letter in the user input. However, it only works with any string with letters only, if user input has a space character (or symbols, but symbols aren't really important for this code), it shows a `ValueError` instead.
How do I make it work with space as well?

```
import string

#Gets every letter in the alphabet:
alphabets = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

#create some list to do something, which will be explained later;
res = []
res2 = []

#Gets user input:
getString = str(input()).lower()

#Gets every letter in the input:
get_all_letters = [x for x in getString]

#Create for loop then find the index of every letter in user input in alphabet, append it to the res list:
for x in range(-1,len(get_all_letters)-1):
  x+=1
  if get_all_letters[x-1] in alphabets:
    m = alphabets.index(get_all_letters[x])
    res.append(m)

#Reverse the alphabet:
reversed_alphabets = alphabets[::-1]

#Create for loop to append every element in the reversed alphabet by given index in the res list to the res2 list:
for x in res:
  res2.append(reversed_alphabets[x])

#Convert the res2 list to string:
n = "".join(res2)

#print it:
print(n)
```

I tried to append a space if the user contains a space out or inside the loop, it runs but it shows an unexpected output instead. So, I decided to remove that. Also here are some example of the input, expected output and my output:

Input: "Hello World"
Expected Output: "svool dilow"
My output: ValueError: ' ' is not in list.

Input: "Cat"
Expect output: "xzg"
My output: "wzg"

Input: "ca t"
Expected output: "xz g"
My output: ValueError: ' ' is not in the list.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What is the value of `x` when you get this error?  That should be your first clue.

Comment: Why do you check `get_all_letters[x-1]` and then fetch `get_all_letters[x]`?  Your -1/+1/-1 stuff with `x` is completely wrong.  Also remember you don't need to turn `alphabets` or `getString` into a list.  What you're doing can be done with strings.  Also, `input` always returns a string.  You don't need `str(...)`.

Comment: Instead of `[x for x in getString]`, you can just use `list(getString)`.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think should be the result of doing `alphabets.index(' ')`? Why? (Did you try reading the documentation? Do you expect the code to try this, when the input contains a space? (If not, why not?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified so that it works, with the unnecessary -1/+1/-1 removed:

```
import string

#Gets every letter in the alphabet:
alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase

#create some list to do something, will be explained later;
res = []
res2 = []

#Gets user input:
getString = input().lower()

#Create for loop then find the index of every letter in user input in alphabet, append it to the res list:
for x in range(len(getString)):
  if getString[x] in alphabets:
    m = alphabets.index(getString[x])
    res.append(m)

#Reverse the alphabet:
reversed_alphabets = alphabets[::-1]

#Create for loop to append every element in the reversed alphabet by given index in the res list to the res2 list:
for x in res:
  res2.append(reversed_alphabets[x])

#Convert the res2 list to string:
n = "".join(res2)

#print it:
print(n)
```

Python fans will note that any for loop that does `range(len(x))` can almost always done better by just iterating through x:

```
for x in getString:
  if x in alphabets:
    m = alphabets.index(x)
    res.append(m)
```

Comment: I often use -1,+1,-1 of a range when I try to access every number or index of an item. But, It helps a lot. I have been learning Python for a while, so solving any medium, hard or easy coding problem is a victory to me.

Comment: Don't do that.  `range(len(N))` gets you the index of every element of N.  No extra manipulation is needed.